# Change background color of Windows 8.1 toolbar option

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, desktop-toolbar

[image]

I recently installed windows 8.1 and I'm having problem with the color of the application options in my toolbar (dark blue). Also the pin icon is too big. How to make it change back to its default color?

Comment: did u try changing the theme?

Comment: Yap. I tried changing the themes and color scheme to no avail.  Only the border color will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the [Update KB3072318](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3072318). This causes the Jumplist glitch. I talked to Microsoft, they are aware of it and will fix it with a new update.